# How to draw on zoomed image in Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, user-interface, zooming

I'm working on a project where I have to do an image editor similar to Paint. I would like to open up an image, zoom in/zoom out if necessary, and then draw on it.

For that, I used Image Viewer and Scribble examples, the only thing different that I added was a QLabel subclass that is supposed to draw lines and other forms with the mouse press/mouse release events. The problem is with the overriden paintEvent.

```
void imLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
   if(tipo != ""){ //draw mode
      QPainter painter(this);
      QRect dirtyRect = event->rect();
      painter.drawImage(dirtyRect,image,dirtyRect);
   }
   else QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

I am able to zoom in normally in the beginning, but when I start drawing the image comes back to its original size, while the rest of the label that is not occupied by the image is completely white, because it kept the zoomed in size.

Is there a way that I can keep the image zoomed in while I draw, just like in Paint?

**UPDATE**

Here's the code of the draw function, maybe it'll help

```
void imLabel::draw(const QPoint &endPoint){
     QPainter painter(&image);
     painter.setPen(QPen(myPenColor, myPenWidth, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin));
     if(tipo == "maoLivre" || tipo == "reta") //draw line or free hand
         painter.drawLine(startPoint, endPoint);
     else{
        int x = startPoint.x(), y = startPoint.y(),
        largura = endPoint.x()- startPoint.x(),
        altura = endPoint.y() - startPoint.y();
        if(tipo == "retangulo") //draw rectangle
             painter.fillRect(x,y,largura,altura,Qt::green);
        else if(tipo == "circulo"){ //draw circle
             painter.setBrush(Qt::green);
             painter.drawEllipse(startPoint,altura,altura);
        }
    }
    modified = true;
    update();
    startPoint = endPoint;
}
```

Comment: If you show your image zoomed, you might have to convert your mouse coordinates considering that zoomed space. The part with the `QLabel`, I didn't understand. In the [Qt Scribble Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html), the `class ScribbleArea` inherits just from `QWidget`. Why should this prevent you from zooming the scribble image in `paintEvent()`? If I were you, I would consider to inherit it from `QAbstractScrollArea` instead. (Zooming could result in seeing only part of the whole image. So, optional scrollbars might be desirable.)

Comment: Just like in Image Viewer example,  the QImage is on a QLabel, and the QLabel is inside a QWidget. When I start I'm able to zoom normally, as you can see in this picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbJJoI3CDojVAHVQv3J_39ofO2VTaTYe/view?usp=sharing . I zoom the QLabel, by resizing it, and then use setScaledContents(true) to make sure the image comes along. The problem is, when I start drawing, this happens: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15PqzFkW_gmUGBZE6JNBQo7ffG0FzyD23/view?usp=sharing . I'm able to draw just fine, but the image resets it's size, and the QLabel keeps the zoomed  size.

Comment: I assumed the problem seems to be on the paintEvent, because when I use the original one the zoom works fine, but the drawing doesn't appear.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you mentioned the "Image Viewer"...

Comment: The only thing that I use from Scribble is draw() and the overriden paintEvent, the rest is from Image Viewer

Comment: So, you draw into the `QImage` which is shown in `paintEvent()`? Sorry, I'm at work and company doesn't allow to access drive.google.com - it's considered as unsafe.

Comment: Exactly. Where can I put the images then?

Comment: There are a variety of [`QPainter::drawImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage) methods. I was assuming you scribble into your `QImage` and then drawing the scribbled `QImage` in your `paintEvent()`. Don't you?

Comment: I updated the original post with the draw function.

Comment: According to the Scribble example, it's supposed to draw on the QImage and copy the QImage onto screen in paintEvent().

Comment: I assume you show your `QImage` scaled. I assume you click into the (scaled painted) image with mouse. Now, it appears that you get mouse coordinates (in pixels, i.e. not scaled) which does not match the coordinates of the scaled image. You have to transform the mouse coordinates into the scaled `QImage` space. I.e. you have to scale your mouse coordinates as well before you can use them as "scribble" coordinates in image, don't you?

Comment: It's a bit tricky for me to do it in head, hence a practical sample. I imagine an image zoom (scale) of 8. One pixel in image covers 8 x 8 pixels in screen. I imagine a click onto coordinates (12, 10). To get the corresponding pixel coordinates in image, I have to _divide_ them by the scale factor what yields (12 / 8, 10 / 8) = (1, 1). (It was integral division.) So, the scribbled pixel in image has coordinates (1, 1). This way it sounds right for me.

Comment: Actually I don't scale the image, I only adjust the QLabel like this:
    scaleFactor *= factor;
imageLabel->resize(scaleFactor * imageLabel->pixmap()->size());
Then I click the option to draw with a line for example, as soon as I click the option in the menu bar, I set draw mode, show a message box showing how to use the line tool, and because I call a message box, it calls the painEvent. Since it's already on draw mode, before I draw anything, it already resizes the image to its original size, but the QLabel keeps the zoom size, leaving a blank space between the image and label borders.

Comment: The zoom and drawing works fine if I scale the image, but image loses qualitiy.